# Raspberry Pi 3B gets really hot when watching YouTube

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

When I watch a YouTube video at 340p with audio on my Raspberry Pi 3B, it gets over 80C without a heat sink. I have an Apple 12W 5.2V ~ 2.4A as my PSU if anyone would ask.

Is this normal or should I be concerned?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50978/discussion-on-question-by-aheagle-raspberry-pi-3b-gets-really-hot-when-watching).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the temperatures and CPU usage you shared in the chat, I believe that what you are experiencing is normal as reviving video over the internet and deciding it is very taxing on it. However a CPU cooler isn't exactly a necessity as the Pi will simply slow itself down to prevent it from over heating. But if you want to watch YouTube in a higher quality or have background tasks running while watching YouTube then I would recommend a heat sync and maybe a fan to prevent thermal throttling.